# Gnu make, multiple sets of grouped targets

Tags: gnu-make

I have a makefile that includes two rules each of which defines a (completely different) grouped target. The intention in each case is (of course) to generate all of the targets by executing the associated recipe once.

If both rules are present, each using the target separator "&:", I get "warning: overriding recipe for target '&'", with the first lines of each of the two recipes cited.

If I change either rule to use the standard target separator ":", the warning goes away.

I can provide extracts from the makefile but believe the above description is as concise as it will get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouped targets were introduced in GNU make version 4.3.

Your version of GNU make is too old and doesn't recognize this syntax (it thinks that `&` is a target name).

Comment: You're right - I checked and my Xubuntu has Version 4.1. Because I run Software Updater frequently it had not occurred to me that the version of Gnu Make would not match the manual I downloaded!

Comment: It's best to look at the manual that is downloaded with the package (you might have to load another package like `make-doc` or similar.  That will be the one that is appropriate for your installed version of GNU make.  Remember that distributions don't always immediately deploy the latest version, especially to critical infrastructure like GNU make.  Unless there's a major bug found, you won't get a newer version until you upgrade to a newer version of the distribution.  You can always build it yourself.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it's sufficient, so people know the question has been answered.  Cheers!